# Rounded Corner Cut-Out with Border; Subtract border size from width and height of child element

Tags: css, border, parent-child, fluid-layout

I've almost got it but I'm stuck on one thing. I'm trying to make the child p tag fluid to the parent div's width and height. I just can't figure out how to get the p element slightly smaller (by 4px I believe) than the parent div so that the right and bottom borders show. Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkUVe/).

And the code in question:

```
.box {
    background: #b2b2b2;
    height: 160px;
    width: 210px;
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.box p {
    color: #fafafa;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

<div class="box"><p class="boxBtm">Some text in the box</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yeah as Smuuf said box-sizing: border-box is the answer. For better
>   understanding on this, here is a good read:

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

> Support
>
> Opera 8.5+: box-sizing
>
> Firefox (any): -moz-box-sizing
>
> Safari 3: -webkit-box-sizing (unprefixed in 5.1+ versions)
>
> IE8+: box-sizingChrome (any): box-sizing

Here's your solution:

```
.box p {
    color: #fafafa;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amrebel/qkUVe/8/

Comment: I also achieved using `width: calc(100% - 54px)` which would be best to use?

Comment: Well there may be other good days to do it as well... but box-sizing: border-box is a good CSS property... Ultimately its your choice... I usually do :

* { box-sizing: border-box; } 

at the beginning. :)

Comment: Yeah it will come in handy as I've encountered width issues before using borders. - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe `box-sizing: border-box;` is your [answer](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0).

Put it into your **.box p** definition:

```
.box p {
    color: #fafafa;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and played around a little bit, any tips on how to implement?